# On pressing TAB key without any data in text field it should show required field validation ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Required field validation is normally done on button clicks. But I want the alert to be shown when we go to the next TAB index. How can I do that in JavaScript---ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(c)
        {
            if(c.value=="")
            {
                alert("The required field cannot left blank");
                c.focus();
            }
        }
</script>
```

Design:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="validate(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript for this for example as mentioned in this link
http://forums.asp.net/t/1376939.aspx

In Page_Load,

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ValidatorOnChange(event);")
```